# How to plot a "differential word cloud" in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization, text-mining

I have a questionnaire with one "open" text box, and 20,000 responses. I'm not planning to read all of them, but I'm thinking of interesting things to do with them. A general tag cloud would not be very interesting (I can predict which words would be the biggest), but it would be fun to split it along another categorical variable and see a tag cloud, or even just a word cloud, of the words that are the most different or most distinct for each categorical variable...

Let's say this is the evaluation for a psych course... Of course "psychology", "lectures", "videos" etc will be the biggest words in general. But if we have a second question called "user category", and say "which words are the most common among "lifelong learners", and the least common among "students""... That would automatically eliminate the super-common words I mentioned above, and might show something interesting...

If there are other interesting ways of visualizing words used compared with different categorical variables (maybe some kind of 2D graph, or network graph?), I'd love to hear about them as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you've basically got your idea pretty well parsed out, I think the missing piece you are looking for is the right scoring function. I recommend using [Term Frequency - Inverse Document Frequency (TF-IDF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf-idf). In your particular example, I recommend grouping all documents sharing a class/tag into a single "document" for that purpose of calculating IDF: that way you will have a TF-IDF score for each word relative to each class instead of relative to the specific document (user response).

You will probably find the [TermDocument](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/vignettes/tm.pdf) function in the tm package useful. You may also want to reference this [SO use case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14820754/819544).

EDIT: As Jonathan suggests below, it actually might not be to your benefit to treat classes as unified documents, in which case calculating the TF-IDFs should be a more straight forward task (i.e. require less manipulation of your dataset/corpus).

Comment: this would be effective for large numbers of classes/tags, but for classes like UserType which divide the total population into a small number of groups, then the "document" definition may be too narrow - if there are 4 types, then DF would only be in increments of 25%! Instead, it might be better to treat each response as a document, and compute TF-IDF by summing up all occurrences in the class and divide by DF across the entire list of responses. Do the same for documents outside the class, and the difference between the TF-IDFs would be your score.

Comment: Yeah, I was actually thinking about this earlier and I agree: it might be better to just treat each response as separate documents. Anyway, OP can play with both options and figure out what he thinks works best.